# Why isn't Xcode running on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: c, xcode

I just downloaded Xcode 6.4 onto my macbook pro with OS X 10.9.5, Thing is it keeps sayings Xcode only works on 10.10.4 or higher? Any suggestions? Would like to learn C.
Any ideas?

Comment: I sugggest you ask this question to the producer of both. Which might not be Microsoft. But from the version number, I would think _that_ might be the problem. So upgrade one or downgrade the other?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: current versions of Xcode require Mac OS X 10.10.4 or later. Install the Yosemite (10.10) update from the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#6.x_series) the latest version of Xcode that will with with OS X 10.9.5 is Xcode 6.2. You can't get this version from the App Store AFAIK, but Apple do keep older versions available for download in [Developer Centre](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). Just go there, sign in if needed, search for Xcode 6.2, and you should be able to download the DMG directly and install.  Or alternatively, here is a [direct link to Xcode 6.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.2/Xcode_6.2.dmg). Sign in may be required.

Alternatively, you could upgrade your OS to the latest if your hardware supports it.